# Finding right path in Cypher Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm working with Flight Analyzer database (https://neo4j.com/graphgist/flight-analyzer).
We have there few nodes and relationships types.
Nodes: 
Airport

```
(SEA:Airport { name:'SEA' })
```

Flight

```
(f0:Flight { date:'11/30/2015 04:24:12', duration:218, distance:1721, airline:'19977' })
```

Ticket

```
(t1f0:Ticket { class:'economy', price:1344.75 })
```

Relationships
Destination

```
(f0)-[:DESTINATION]->(ORD)
```

Origin

```
(f0)-[:ORIGIN]->(SEA)
```

Assign

```
(t1f0)-[:ASSIGN]->(f0)
```

Now I need to find some path and I have problem with that connection ORIGIN - FLIGHT - DESTINATION.
I need to find all airports that are connected to LAX airport with sum of ticket prices < 3000.

I tried

```
MATCH path = (origin:Airport { name:"LAX" })<-[r:ORIGIN|DESTINATION*..5]->(destination:Airport)
WHERE REDUCE(s = 0, n IN [x IN NODES(path) WHERE 'Flight' IN LABELS(x)] |
s + [(n)<-[:ASSIGN]-(ticket) | ticket.price][0]
) < 3000
RETURN path
```

but in this solution LAX can be ORIGIN and DESTINATION too. I only want to chose paths that always have the same order aiport1 <- origin - flight1 - destination -> airport2 <- origin - flight2 - destination -> aiport etc..

I need to include departure and arrive time so
flight1 date + duration < flight2 date then flight2 date + duration < flight3 date etc...

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATED]

This query should check that:

- matched paths have alternating `ORIGIN/DESTINATION` relationships, and
- every departing flight lands at least 30 minutes before the next departing flight (if any), and
- the sum of the ticket prices of the `Flight` nodes (which are every other node starting at the second one) < 3000

```
MATCH p = (origin:Airport {name: 'LAX'})-[:ORIGIN|DESTINATION*..5]-(destination:Airport)
WHERE
  ALL(i IN RANGE(0, LENGTH(p)-1) WHERE
    TYPE(RELATIONSHIPS(p)[i]) = ['ORIGIN', 'DESTINATION'][i] AND
    (i%4 <> 1 OR (i + 2) > LENGTH(p) OR
      (apoc.date.parse(NODES(p)[i].date,'m','MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss') + NODES(p)[i].duration + 30) < apoc.date.parse(NODES(p)[i+2].date,'m','MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss'))
  ) AND
  REDUCE(s = 0, n IN [k IN RANGE(1, LENGTH(p), 2) | NODES(p)[k]] |
    s + [(n)<-[:ASSIGN]-(ticket) | ticket.price][0]
  ) < 3000
RETURN p
```

The query uses the [apoc.date.parse](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/temporal/datetime-conversions/#datetime-available-procedures-apoc.date.parse) function to convert each `date` into the number of epoch minutes, so that a `duration` (assumed to also be in minutes) can be added to it.

Comment: I don't know how but it seems it works. Unfortunetly this code doesn't provide the part about departures and arrive time

Comment: Right now it doesn't work. Is there an option to create a new relantionship base on existing relantionships and nodes? For example can I create relationship with with all values from ticket, flight and connected to origin and destination airport?

Comment: You could do that, but storing redundant data is not recommended, as it adds a lot more complexity (and is hard to keep everything consistent), and uses up more resources.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you should create new relationships like flyto from an airport to an airport with ticket price and ticket class. it can be useful.
then you can find flights easier.

```
 match 
(a:Airport )<-[:ORIGIN]-(f:Flight)-[:DESTINATION ]->(b:Airport ),
(f)-[:ASSIGN]-(t:Ticket)
CREATE (a)-[r:FLY_TO {price:t.price,Class:t.class} ]->(b)
```